# class not visible Clipboard

Tags: c#, clipboard

Please tell me why the Visual Studio does not see me, does not see the class? I am using core 7.0

```
using System.Windows;

namespace Labaratornay
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string textData = "check";
            Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Text, (Object)textData); // name "Clipboard" and "DataFormats" does not exist in the current context
        }
    }
}
```

I will be grateful for any of your help. Thanks in advance for this

Comment: You've not imported them?

Comment: please include actual error message

Comment: The Clipboard class is not supported by .NET 7.0

Comment: @MarkBenningfield is right. You can use an alternative NuGet package: [TextCopy](https://github.com/CopyText/TextCopy) - A cross platform package to copy text to and from the clipboard.

Comment: Mark Benningfield, I understand, thank you very much. Is there a replacement for this class?

Comment: @Maciej Los oooh, thank you very much! Everything works, I used the nuget-package TextCopy

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, you need to install the NuGet package [TextCopy](https://github.com/CopyText/TextCopy)

```
using TextCopy;

namespace Labaratornay
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string textData = "check";
            var clipboard = new Clipboard();
            clipboard.SetText(textData);
        }
    }
}
```

Special thanks @Mark Benningfield for help!